# How do I write a Django query that does date math when executed as PostGres SQL?

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql, datetime

I'm using Django and Python 3.7.  I'm writing a Django query to be run on a PostGres 9.4 db, but having trouble figuring out how to form my expression wrapper so that I add a number of seconds (an integer) to an existing date column.  I tried the below

```
hour_filter = ExtractHour(ExpressionWrapper(
            F("article__created_on") + timedelta(0,
                                                 F("article__websitet__avg_time_in_seconds_to_reach_ep")),
            output_field=models.DateTimeField)
        ),
)
```

but I'm getting the error

```
unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: F
```

Any ideas how I can rewrite my ExpressionWrapper to do the date math inside the PostGres query?

**Edit;** Here are the models and relevant fields ...

```
class Website(models.Model):
    ...
    avg_time_in_seconds_to_reach_ep = models.FloatField(default=0, null=True)


class Article(models.Model):
    objects = ArticleManager()
    website = models.ForeignKey(Website, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='articlesite')
```

Comment: Have you tried converting the value returned by the `F(...)` expression to `int` or  `float`? Ex: `... + timedelta(0, int(F("article_websitet__avg_time_in_seconds_to_reach_ep")), ...`

Comment: @Dave can you show us the related models for this?

Comment: @Caleb, I edited my question to include the models and their relevant fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add [database functions to Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions), for this you can add a function for the [INTERVAL statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) in postgres

```
class IntervalSeconds(Func):

    function = 'INTERVAL'
    template = "(%(expressions)s * %(function)s '1 seconds')"
```

You can then use this function in your queries to add seconds to a datetime

```
YourModel.objects.annotate(
    attr=ExpressionWrapper(
        F("article__created_on") + IntervalSeconds(F("article__websitet__avg_time_in_seconds_to_reach_ep")),
        output_field=models.DateTimeField()
    ),
)
```

The output of the `IntervalSeconds` function is a 1 second [Postgres interval](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-interval/) multiplied by the field passed to it. This can be added and subtracted from a timestamp. You could make a generic `Interval` function that doesn't just take seconds, this is a little more complex

The `ExpressionWrapper` is required to convert the result to a datetime object

Comment: Thx, gave this a whirl.  In my ExpressionWrapper I put 'F("article__created_on") + IntervalSeconds(F("article__website__avg_time_in_seconds_to_reach_ep")' but got the error, "invalid input syntax for type interval: ""articlesum_website"."avg_time_in_seconds_to_reach_ep" seconds"
LINE 1: ...FROM ("articlesum_article"."created_on" + INTERVAL '"articlesu...'

Comment: Updated the answer with a slightly better function